# Snaphat hat bug

Tags: bug, status-completed

I seem to have gotten this hat undeservingly because it is supposedly for "answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked..." and I got it for a question more than a month old.

[In states where marijuana is legal did prescription painkiller sales decrease?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35817/in-states-where-marijuana-is-legal-did-prescription-painkiller-sales-decrease/36349#36349)

Comment: I don't think that's the point of the hat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm this is a bug, we are deciding how to fix it.

Fixed, details here: [Why was the snaphat not awarded? Or why was it awarded incorrectly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288529/why-was-the-snaphat-not-awarded-or-why-was-it-awarded-incorrectly/288530#288530)